# A html file without any html or body tags but only a div renders in all browsers

Tags: html

I was taken aback when I saw that if I saved the following content into a file with 'htm' extension, then it renders and also displays the JavaScript alert.

I was under the impression that a browser would definitely need html, and body tags at the very least to render a html file.

**Is it normal for browsers to do this and does this cause any security-related issue?**

```
       <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td  style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <div style='color:red;height:100%;width:100%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;border-width:1px;border-color:blue;border-style:solid;vertical-align:middle' id="div1">
                        Does this render in a Browser, since there are html, head and body tags?
                        <div id='div2' style='height"100%;width:100%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;border-width:1px;border-color:green;border-style:solid;'>Hello! Will the browser show this?</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <script type='text/javascript'>    alert('showing without tags');</script>
```

Comment: Most browsers try to compensate for poorly written code and will do their best to execute any code they can understand.

Comment: [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) to the rescue! And also on [whatwg](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: So this is could not cause any issues?

Comment: Quirks mode is only for IE, if I understand correctly. But this happens in Chrome and FF also.

Comment: @Sunil - No, it isn't IE only.

Comment: It renders, but it is not in standards mode, so you have no idea how each browser will in fact end up parsing and rendering.

Comment: @Oded How do modern browsers react to quirks mode?

Comment: @Oded: So it seems this behavior is not going to be removed in future from browsers. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jan - see the link to whatwg on my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175542/a-html-file-without-any-html-or-body-tags-but-only-a-div-renders-in-all-browsers#comment19643584_14175542).

Comment: Thoughts? About what exactly? This is normal - I don't know what your security concerns are and what this behaviour has anything to do with security.

Comment: @Oded: Ok. I was using this fact in one of my web pages, and was just making sure that it will not fail because html tags are missing in some future release of IE or FF or Chrome.

Comment: @Sunil - It is not standard HTML, so you can't count on what future browsers will do and how they will go into quirks mode.

Comment: @Ode: I get it now. Do you want to post  your answer so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing such HTML (without a doctype), most browsers go into [quirks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) [mode](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/).

How they interpret the HTML and render it at this point is not standardized and is implementation specific.

This also means that you can't rely on the behaviour staying the same in future versions.

In short - do not rely on browsers today rendering such HTML in any specific way - it might change.

As for your security concerns - I don't really see what relation this has to security (apart from normal browser security issues).

Comment: Quirks mode has nothing to do with validity. That is determined solely by the Doctype.

Comment: As Quentin’s answer describes, lack of `html` and `body` tags does not make a document invalid and does not cause any browser-dependent behavior.

Comment: So it seems that this type of html without html and body tags will still be rendered  in future versions?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers determine if a document is HTML or not based on the file extension (for local files) or the Content-Type HTTP header (for files accessed over HTTP), not based on anything to do with the content in the document (with the exception of some versions of Internet Explorer which will sniff non text/html documents to see if they might be HTML).

Once a browser has determined a document is HTML, it will render it as best it is able despite anything that might make it invalid. A combination of browsers being written to cope with bad documents and bad documents being written because browsers can cope with them has led to a spiral of ever increasingly powerful error recovery routines in all browsers.

The missing `html` and `body` tags don't contribute to it being invalid though, the start and end tags for those elements are optional in all versions of HTML (although not XHTML which has no optional tags). The document would be valid if it was given a suitable Doctype and a title.

There are no intrinsic security problems with serving invalid HTML to browsers. You do have to be careful about what user generated content you allow to be added to your site (but you'd have to be careful there even if browsers only accepted valid documents) and sometimes bad HTML can exploit security holes in browsers (but it is the responsibility of the browser vendor to fix those problems).

Comment: So it seems that this type of behavior is going to be always there in future releases of major browsers?